# time.Sleep not waking up

Tags: go

I ran several processes on my work desktop for several days. This morning all these processes pretty much stopped working. After some debugging I found out that after executing `time.Sleep`, the execution flow would just get stuck there and never wake up. So while everyone on my team was freaking out I just restarted my Windows 10 PC and people thought it was a desperation reboot. I guess luckily the issue went away after restart *shrugs*.

I wonder if anyone has experienced this before or has any idea what may be the cause? I read in another post that `time.Sleep` basically schedules when execution resumes by computing the absolute time in the OS, but AFAIK the date/time settings never changed.

I realize this may be difficult to diagnose but I've never encountered this problem on non-Windows machines. Needless to say I hate Windows and am biased towards Unix, but I promise to give Windows a chance if someone can give me some reasonable explanations on this bug.

Comment: There's literally no way to answer this question. 1. You haven't explained the problem, except that something "stopped working" (whatever that means) and that something "got stuck" (again: what does that mean?). 2. You haven't included any code.

Comment: So I logged something before and after I call time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond) and the second log call never executes

Comment: Let me be explicit: Update your question. Add _actual code_ that _actually fails_. And explain the output or behavior you observe, and the output or behavior you expected instead.

Answer (score 2):

(This is not going to be an answer — for the reasons below — but rather a couple of hints.)

The question lacks crucial context.
Was the desktop put to sleep (or hibernated) and woken up — so you expected the processes to continue from where they left off?
Are you sure the relevant goroutines were stuck in `time.Sleep` and not something else?

The last question is of the most interest but it's unanswerable as is.
To make it so, you'd need to arm your long-running processes with some means of debugging.

The simplest approach which works in a crude way but without much fuss is to *kill* your process in an interesting way: send it the `SIGQUIT` signal and the Go runtime will crash the process — dumping the stacktraces of the active goroutines to the process' `stderr`.
(Of course, this implies you did not trap this signal in your process' code.)

Windows does not have signals, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> [should work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals) like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> in a Unix terminal where it typically sends `SIGQUIT` to the foreground process.

This approach could be augmented by tweaking the `GOTRACEBACK` environment variable — to cite [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/):

> The `GOTRACEBACK` variable controls the amount of output generated when
>   a Go program fails due to an unrecovered panic or an unexpected
>   runtime condition. By default, a failure prints a stack trace for the
>   current goroutine, eliding functions internal to the run-time system,
>   and then exits with exit code 2. The failure prints stack traces for
>   all goroutines if there is no current goroutine or the failure is
>   internal to the run-time. `GOTRACEBACK=none` omits the goroutine stack
>   traces entirely. `GOTRACEBACK=single` (the default) behaves as described
>   above. `GOTRACEBACK=all` adds stack traces for all user-created
>   goroutines. `GOTRACEBACK=system` is like “all” but adds stack frames for
>   run-time functions and shows goroutines created internally by the
>   run-time. `GOTRACEBACK=crash` is like “system” but crashes in an
>   operating system-specific manner instead of exiting. For example, on
>   Unix systems, the crash raises `SIGABRT` to trigger a core dump. For
>   historical reasons, the `GOTRACEBACK` settings 0, 1, and 2 are synonyms
>   for none, all, and system, respectively. The `runtime/debug` package's
>   `SetTraceback` function allows increasing the amount of output at run
>   time, but it cannot reduce the amount below that specified by the
>   environment variable. See
>   https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetTraceback.

So, if you'd be running your process with `GOTRACEBACK=crash`, you could be able to not only collect the stacktraces but also a dump file (on typical Linux-based systems these days this requires running under `ulimit -c unlimited` as well).
Unfortunately, on Windows it's *almost* there but [not yet](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20498); still something to keep an eye on.

A more hard-core approach is to make your process dump the stacks of goroutines when you ask for that using custom-implemented way — https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/ and https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug contain all the stuff required to do that.
You might look at how https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/ is implemented and/or just use it right away.